# Populate a value to below rows in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table like this :

```
   +----+---------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| id | action  | group |     book      | book_type  | book_per_row | book_status |      time      |
+----+---------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
|  1 | welcome | hello | null          | null       | null         | null        | 6/27/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | welcome | hello | null          | null       | null         | null        | 6/28/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | welcome | hello | null          | null       | null         | null        | 6/29/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | buy     | order | little prince | literature | 1            | bought      | 6/29/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | buy     | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 6/30/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | buy     | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/1/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | buy     | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/2/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | buy     | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/3/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | search  | order | little prince | literature | 0            | bought      | 7/4/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | search  | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/5/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | search  | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/6/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/6/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | buy     | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | buy     | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | exit    | exit  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:13  |
|  1 | exit    | exit  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:13  |
+----+---------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
```

And I want to make it like this(when there is a null between a book, I want to replace it with book's name, book_type, book_status):

```
+----+---------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| id | action  | group |     book      | book_type  | book_per_row | book_status |      time      |
+----+---------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
|  1 | welcome | hello | null          | null       | null         | null        | 6/27/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | welcome | hello | null          | null       | null         | null        | 6/28/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | welcome | hello | null          | null       | null         | null        | 6/29/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | buy     | order | little prince | literature | 1            | bought      | 6/29/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | buy     | order | little prince | literature | 0            | bought      | 6/30/2022 0:10 |
|  1 | buy     | order | little prince | literature | 0            | bought      | 7/1/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | buy     | order | little prince | literature | 0            | bought      | 7/2/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | buy     | order | little prince | literature | 0            | bought      | 7/3/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | search  | order | little prince | literature | 0            | bought      | 7/4/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | search  | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/5/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | search  | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/6/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/6/2022 0:10  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | buy     | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | buy     | order | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | auth    | auth  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:11  |
|  1 | exit    | exit  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:13  |
|  1 | exit    | exit  | null          | null       | null         | null        | 7/7/2022 0:13  |
+----+---------+-------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
```

I tried something like this:

```
select id,action,group,
case when book is null then lag(book)over(partition by id order by time asc) as book else book end as book,
case when book_type is null then lag(book_type)over(partition by id order by time asc) as book_type else book_type end as book,
case when book_status is null then lag(book_status)over(partition by id order by time asc) as book_status else book_status end as book,
time
from table.
```

But I can only populate only the lead row from the one that has value in book, book type, book_per_row, book_status.

Comment: *`case when is null`* When what is null?

Comment: @Shmiel Sorry, my fault. I have updated.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with `LAG` over a window, but the wrong function.

I generated [this sql](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22latest%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22action%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22book%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22book_type%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22book_per_row%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22book_status%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22time%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22group_by%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22action%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22action%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A1%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A2%7D%5D%7D%2C%22order_by%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A7%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22time%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22time%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A7%7D%5D%7D%2C%22nulls%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22ignore%22%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22latest%22%7D) with the `latest` function for snowflake, which I believe has the same window function as impala called `LAST_VALUE`.

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  action, 
  group, 
  time, 
  LAST_VALUE(book ignore NULLS) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id, 
    action, 
    group 
    ORDER BY 
      time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
      AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS LATEST_book, 
  LAST_VALUE(book_type ignore NULLS) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id, 
    action, 
    group 
    ORDER BY 
      time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
      AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS LATEST_book_type, 
  LAST_VALUE(book_per_row ignore NULLS) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id, 
    action, 
    group 
    ORDER BY 
      time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
      AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS LATEST_book_per_row, 
  LAST_VALUE(book_status ignore NULLS) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id, 
    action, 
    group 
    ORDER BY 
      time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
      AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS LATEST_book_status, 
FROM 
  table
```

I don't currently have access to Impala, so I'm hoping this works for you!

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work.